# ASP CLASSIC LIST/MENU if statement

Tags: asp-classic

below is my ASP classic code.i having a problem when put if else statement like that..actually it's not working..what i want to do is when i select USA then submit it will show selected USA..default is ALL.sorry for my bad English.

```
<% Response.write"<form action=""untitled.asp"" method=""post"">"
   Response.write"<select name=""country"">"
   Response.write"<option selected>ALL</option>"
   Response.write" <option value=""1"" if request(""country"")=""1"" then 
   Response.Write""selected"">USA</option>"
   Response.write" <option value=""2"" if request(""country"")=""2"" then 
   Response.Write""selected"">BRAZIL</option>"
   Response.write"<label>"
   Response.write" <input type=submit name=button id=button value=Submit />"
   Response.write"</label>"
   Response.write"</form>"
%>
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your basic syntax is wrong. This is how it should be done:

```
Response.write " <option value=""1"""
If request("country")="1" then 
    Response.Write " selected=""selected"""
End If
Response.Write ">USA</option>"
```

And same for the second option. To make it more flexible and readable, use a function:

```
Function BuildOption(sValue, sRequestKey, sText)
    Dim sHTML
    sHTML = "<option value=""" & sValue & """"
    If Request(sRequestKey)=sValue Then 
        sHTML = sHTML & " selected=""selected"""
    End If
    sHTML = sHTML & ">" & sText & "</option>"
    BuildOption = sHTML
End Function
```

Then use it like this:

```
Response.write BuildOption("1", "country", "USA")
Response.write BuildOption("2", "country", "BRAZIL")
```